# How do you apply a Weight Factor to an M2M Dimensional Relationship in SSAS?

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssas, bids

I have a many-to-many relationship with a weight factor column in the bridge table but I don't know how to make use of this when developing my cube in BIDS.  Via Google, I have found many descriptions of what a weight factor is and why you would use one (I understand all this perfectly), but I can't find a practical tutorial of how to configure this in a cube in BIDS.

Click-by-click instructions would be ideal but if some one could at least point me at the right window I could probably figure out the rest.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the weight factor and the value you are applying the weight to are on different Measure Groups, you can use the MeasureExpression property of the Measure